# Does jQuery UI's sortable has a bug when the handle is outside the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of dynamically added fields which uses jquery UI's `sortable()`. I have a dragging icon inside a `absolute` positioned tip that has each fields options.

When I try to sort the fields up and down, the placeholder (it's a red box in the demo) doesn't move. After some testing I found that If I remove the `position: absolute;` css rule using firebug it works, but that breaks the layout.

Here is a demo of the problem: http://mahersalam.co.cc/projects/namodgMaker/

First add 2 or more fields, then try to drag one of them to see the problem.

How can I fix this problem ?

**Update**: I tried to make the tip outside of the sorted field by using negative margins and floating and the problem still happened, maybe it's a jquery UI bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Chrome? It seems to work there or I have not understood your app.

Comment: It works in chrome only if the cursor is on the moving field. Other browsers (FF) doesn't share this behavior. I reported this to jquery ui bug tracker. Thanks for trying :)